# Rfid rc522 on Raspberry stops reading after long time

Tags: python, rfid, raspberry-pi4

I'm working on an attendance system with a Raspberry pi 4 and 2 rc522 rfid readers.
When the badge is read, if ID is present within the internal database, a relay module with a led is activated for 1 second.

Everything works fine but after long time (more than 6 hours) the second rc522 stops reading.

I use this library: https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python/tree/master/mfrc522 copied into two directories with different names.
One is untouched but the other one is edited at line 128 (mfrc522/MFRC522.py): "device=0" => "device=1".

I tried parallel and series wiring, no difference. Also tried swapping the readers, no difference.
So it's not an hardware problem.

I have a while loop to check actual time so the readers can only read during established opening hours.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import mfrc522Lib.mfrc522
import mfrc522Lib2.mfrc522
import mysql.connector
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)


#variables
reader1 = mfrc522Lib.mfrc522.SimpleMFRC522()
reader2 = mfrc522Lib2.mfrc522.SimpleMFRC522()
open1 = '08:15:00'
close1 = '11:45:00'
open2 = '13:30:00'
close2 = '17:45:00'
update = '23:00:00'
now = '%H:%M:%S'
on = 0
off = 0
upload = 0
db_con = 0
server_con = 0
relay = 18
GPIO.setup(relay,GPIO.OUT)


#functions
def db_connect():
        global db
        global db_con
        global dbcursor

        try:
                db = mysql.connector.connect(
                        host="localhost",
                        user="user",
                        password="password",
                        database="database"
                )
        except:
                db_con = 0
                print("Database not accessible")
        else:
                dbcursor = db.cursor()
                db_con = 1
                print("Database accessible")


def server_connect():
        global dbserver
        global server_con
        global cursorserver
        try:
                dbserver = mysql.connector.connect(
                        host="serverIP",
                        port="serverPort",
                        user="user",
                        password="password",
                        database="server"
                )

        except:
                server_con = 0
                print("Server offline")
        else:
                cursorserver = dbserver.cursor()
                server_con = 1
                print("Server online")


def read_badge(action, rfid):
    db_connect()
    if db_con == 1
            select = "SELECT RFID FROM Users WHERE RFID = " + str(rfid)
            dbcursor.execute(select)
            result = dbcursor.fetchone()

            if dbcursor.rowcount >= 1:
                  insert = "INSERT INTO Accesses (RFID, Action) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
                    values = (str(rfid), action,)
                    dbcursor.execute(insert, values)
                    db.commit()
            db.close()
                    if action == 'In':
                            print("User authorized, recorderd ingress")
                    elif azione == 'Out':
                            print("User authorized, recorded exit")
                    GPIO.output(relay,GPIO.HIGH)
                    time.sleep(1)
                    GPIO.output(relay,GPIO.LOW)
                    time.sleep(10)
            else:
                    db.close()
            print("User not authorized")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    

#main program, this is for checking if program started without terminal prompt as the program run after boot with sysem.d
GPIO.output(relay,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)
GPIO.output(relay,GPIO.LOW)

try:
    while True:
        while time.strftime(now) >= open1 and time.strftime(now) <= close1 or time.strftime(now) >= open2 and time.strftime(now) <= close2:
            if on == 0:
                print("Access open")
                on = 1
                off = 0
                upload = 0

            id1 = reader1.read_id_no_block()
            id2 = reader2.read_id_no_block()

            if id1 != None:
                read_badge('In', id1)
            if id2 != None:
                read_badge('Out', id2)

        else:
            if off == 0:
                print("Access close")
                off = 1
                on = 0

        if time.strftime(now) >= update and upload == 0:
            db_connect()
            server_connect()
            if server_con == 1:

                #upload all registered accesses to server and clean accesses table on local database

                upload = 1
             dbserver.close()
             db.close()

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I'm thinking of using *os.system('sudo reboot') between the two opening hours and after the night update but it's my last option.

Comment: Can you provide more of your script please?
I have runned the same issue a long time ago but i don t have enough elements to answer you now...

Comment: Added the "full" code, I skipped some non essential and debugging code

Comment: I think you should replace your `finally` by an `Except` in order to print out any error.

It could come from your RFID reader (I added a lot of try excepts in the lib). Or from your database code. Here if there is any error, your programm shutdown without tells you anything...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but right now the program does not generate errors and does not stop, in fact it has been running for almost a week. I just have to reboot it because the reader stops reading but the program would keep running.

Comment: Do you have any idea where the programm stop running? Maybe you could log to debug... ?

Comment: The program doesn't stop running, it's only the second reader that stops reading after long time.

Comment: If you invert the readers, what happend? It could help you to know if the problem is hardware or software.

Comment: As I've already written, swapping readers makes no difference and also swapping between series and parallel wiring makes no difference, so it's not hardware.
I think it's something related to library.

Comment: Here my own modified libs for ultralights: https://github.com/REZALKIN/PICONFLEX2000-FONCTIONS/blob/master/RFID.py
and https://github.com/REZALKIN/PICONFLEX2000-CLIENT/blob/master/MFRC522.py

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to take a look at it.

Comment: Ok, I added the card check before reading its id and did various test but the problem remains. I'm thinking to use the status check to trigger a service restart.

Comment: Yes, I don t know how to help you for having a good solution. You have to run a restart or continue searching...

Comment: I built something similar and encountered this same issue without fail 7 total readers  across 2 facilities. Nightly reboot and regularly restarting the service on some pi's is the fix. (bandaid)